# Scraping a whole site using vba

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I've created a parser which is able to parse the full content of houzz.com. After going to the given address, it parses the sub-category links from the left sided bar. Each sub-category links spreads across several pages with pagination. Then it goes to the main page of each sub category links and parses the content over there. I tried to do the whole thing with my level best.

```
Sub HouzzFull()
Const url = "https://www.houzz.com/professionals/"
Dim http As New ServerXMLHTTP60
Dim html As New HTMLDocument, htm As New HTMLDocument, hmm As New HTMLDocument
Dim str As String, link As String, main As String
Dim topics As Object, topic As Object
Dim links As Object, post As Object, gist As HTMLHtmlElement

With http
    .Open "GET", url, False
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With
Set topics = html.getElementsByClassName("sidebar-item-label")

    For i = 1 To topics.Length - 1
    str = topics(i).href

    With http
        .Open "GET", str, False
        .send
        htm.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    Set links = htm.getElementsByClassName("pageNumber")
        For y = 0 To links.Length - IIf(links.Length > 0, 1, 0)

        If y > 0 Then
        link = links(y).href

        With http
            .Open "GET", link, False
            .send
            htm.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        End With

        End If

        Set topic = htm.getElementsByClassName("pro-title")
            For Each post In topic
            main = post.href

            With http
                .Open "GET", main, False
                .send
                hmm.body.innerHTML = .responseText
            End With

                For Each gist In hmm.getElementsByClassName("container profile-carded")
                    x = x + 1
                    With gist.getElementsByClassName("profile-full-name")
                        If .Length Then Cells(x, 1) = .Item(0).innerText
                    End With
                    With gist.getElementsByClassName("info-list-text")
                        If .Length > 1 Then Cells(x, 2) = Replace(.Item(1).innerText, "Contact:", "")
                    End With
                    With gist.getElementsByClassName("info-list-text")
                        If .Length > 2 Then Cells(x, 3) = Replace(.Item(2).innerText, "Location:", "")
                    End With
                    With gist.getElementsByClassName("click-to-call-link text-gray-light trackMe")
                        If .Length Then Cells(x, 4) = .Item(0).phone
                    End With
                    With gist.getElementsByClassName("proWebsiteLink")
                        If .Length Then Cells(x, 5) = .Item(0).href
                    End With
                Next gist
            Next post
        Next y
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a way to run an audit of just html flat files then scrape each element text into excel to ensure you're using the correct classnames and capturing any new updated ones?

Answer (score 1):

I have a couple thoughts:

Be explicit in defining your constant called url, i.e.

```
Private Const url As String = "https://www.houzz.com/professionals/"
```

Be consistent in how you group your variable declarations. You've grouped some, but not others.

I'm thinking you can have one function that returns responseText each time you do this:

```
With http
    .Open "GET", url, False
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With
```

...and for htm, and hmm

When you use With, End With but only have one line between them, the excessive nesting doesn't aid readability and defeats the purpose of using With, End With. IMHO it would be clearer to just name it out explicitly.I'm thinking something along these lines:

```
Set foo = gist.getElementsByClassName("profile-full-name")
If foo.Length Then Cells(x, 1) = foo.Item(0).innerText
```

The code inside `For Each post in Topic` should be indented like you indented `For Each gist In hmm.getElementsByClassName("container profile-carded")`.